# Invoke executable file from VF page

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to invoke an executable file present on my desktop (Location : E/setup.exe) from a VF page. Please find code snippet below :

Code:

```
<apex:page >

  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    function downloadDraftVersion(){

        var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
        var commandtoRun = "file:///E:/googledrivesync.exe"; 
        oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun,"","","open","1");   
    }    
</script>

  <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock title="Run Software">
        <apex:commandButton value="Run" onclick="downloadDraftVersion();"/>

  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

While I click command button 'Run' , nothing happens. Any insight is greatly appreciated. Just to add, I have read from Forums : It would just run in IE, since FF/Chrome has many security settings which wouldn't allow this behavior.

Comment: your downloadDraftVersion() method executes right ? If that is the case the problem is likely not related to salesforce at all. Ifso you'd better ask this on stackoverflow where there are more javascript, IE, and other developers active.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, there are some programs that simply aren't going to run using these methods any longer. In this particular case, you're trying to initiate a program that's going to make a call-out from your machine to the web to sync the hard drive with Google Drive in the cloud. That presents a security issue for both Salesforce and for your machine.

When certain MS services are called, these hacks definitely do not work. Two years ago, our Developer User Group in Dallas attempted to use this approach to integrate sound editing software (Audacity) with Salesforce for a Non-Profit during Dallas Give Camp and couldn't make it work. After consulting with Microsoft we discovered why. I don't recall the precise details, but seem to recall that it had to do with OBDC drivers that got invoked when the program attempted to launch from a browser. I suspect that's what's happening with your situation as well.

Your best bet would be to try the Google Chrome or Mozilla Forums to see if they have any additional information or guidance they can provide. I recall visiting the Mozilla site at the time.